# Google Sheets - Import Rows Conditionally From Another Sheet While Preserving Links

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Title says it all.

Importrange is not conditional but does preserve links.
Query(Importrange(...)...) makes it conditional but then breaks links.

Is there a way to do this via Google Apps Script or some other formula(s) that I am unaware of?

Specific problem:
Private sheet managed by me, and public sheet which wants only certain rows exposed while preserving links.  There is a column in the private sheet with a simple checkbox that when checked the items should be hidden on the public sheet.

EDIT: Ended up solving this by creating a second sheet within the private sheet and using Filter() to remove the unwanted rows, then I used Importrange on the public sheet from this new filtered sheet.

Comment: You can do this with scripts but why no do your query on a separate sheet in your private sheet and then import that range from the helper sheet?

Comment: Query will always remove links and I need to preserve links, unless I'm not understanding your suggestion.

Comment: Your comment sparked another idea however, which was to use Filter in a second sheet within the main sheet and then use Importrange from that, and it worked!  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this by creating a second sheet within the private sheet and using Filter() to remove the unwanted rows, then I used Importrange on the public sheet from this new filtered sheet.